# 25% battery warning popup

Tags: battery, htc-one-m8, popup

I know this is a duplicate of past questions... But I've tried the suggestion in the first question and it didn't work. And I can't reply to the initial post, so I have to make a duplicate. 
My power saver settings are off. And the popup still pops up.

[image: 25% battery warning]